# LINQ query to output key count value pairs

Tags: linq, list, dictionary, ravendb

There are about half a million RavenDB documents of Customers. One of the properties is "City".. how can I write a LINQ query to get a list of all occurence of a each city with its count. For example, if a thousand customer documents have "NY" as city value, then I need a list of cities with count like NY 1000; LA 200, OR 1300 , BO 5000 etc..

This is what I wrote initially..

```
 Dictionary<string,int> cityStats = session.Query<Customer>()
                    .ToList()
                    .GroupBy(x => x.City)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Count())
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

But this does not look like its giving me accurate results.. so i changed the maximum requests allowed property (I know its not recommended) just to see if it changes the result.. but keeping maxrequest value to 500000 also brings me same result. I know for sure there are about half a million customer documents , so it needs to add up to match.

Comment: Is there a reason you called ToList?

Comment: Without ToList, I am not able to group by.. which is essential to group and get count by city name

Comment: Hi. I just realized that RavenDB does not support SelectMany, GroupBy and Join. If this is of any help: http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/using-linq-to-query-ravendb. It says to use Map/Reduce indexes. (This is only a result of searching. I do not use RavenDB.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a map-reduce index to do this.  Here's a short console program that demonstrates:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Raven.Client.Document;
using Raven.Client.Indexes;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  public class Customer
  {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
  }

  public class Customers_ByCity : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Customer, Customers_ByCity.Result>
  {
    public Customers_ByCity()
    {
      Map = customers => from customer in customers
                         select new
                         {
                           customer.City,
                           Count = 1
                         };

      Reduce = results => from result in results
                          group result by result.City
                          into g
                          select new
                          {
                            City = g.Key,
                            Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count)
                          };
    }

    public class Result
    {
      public string City { get; set; }
      public int Count { get; set; }
    }
  }

  class Program
  {
    private static void Main()
    {
      var documentStore = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://localhost:8080" };
      documentStore.Initialize();
      IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(Program).Assembly, documentStore);

      using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
      {
        session.Store(new Customer { Name = "John", City = "NY" });
        session.Store(new Customer { Name = "Jane", City = "NY" });
        session.Store(new Customer { Name = "Jim", City = "NY" });
        session.Store(new Customer { Name = "Sally", City = "LA" });
        session.Store(new Customer { Name = "Sam", City = "LA" });
        session.Store(new Customer { Name = "Suzie", City = "LA" });
        session.Store(new Customer { Name = "Sarah", City = "LA" });

        session.SaveChanges();
      }

      using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
      {
        // In a real app, you probably don't want to wait for nonstale results.
        // You will also want to consider what to do if you have more than one page of results (more than 1024 cities)

        var counts = session.Query<Customers_ByCity.Result, Customers_ByCity>()
          .Customize(x=> x.WaitForNonStaleResults())
          .Take(1024);

        foreach (var result in counts)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", result.City, result.Count);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```